# What constitutes as a page? Single or double spaced on google docs?

Tags: pages

I am currently writing a teen novel in google docs.  Right now, I'm considering a page single spaced. What is the industry standard for what a page is considered?

Answer (score 2):

Generally, a page is anywhere from **250-400 words**.  Sometimes less, sometimes more.  300 words is a good number if you're trying to estimate how many physical pages your printed novel will be (but keep in mind, physical page count is affected by the size of the page, the size of the text, etc.).

In Google Docs, highlight your text (ctrl+a highlights everything) and click **ctrl+shift+c** to see your word count.  Divide that number by 300 to get, roughly, your page count.

Word count is definitely the "industry standard".

Answer (score 0):

Industry standard is not to count pages but words.  Also, when submitting a manuscript to publishers, industry standard is to double space your work.

For more guidelines see:

[Shunn.net](http://www.shunn.net/format/story.html)

[Writersdigest.com](http://www.writersdigest.com/online-editor/what-are-the-guidelines-for-formating-a-manuscript)

Comment: Word count is the industry standard in almost all settings, sorry.

Comment: Ah... yeah, you're right.  I fixated on the single spaced comment and didn't actually answer the question.  Editing to fix.